# Why is the string showing as numbers?

Tags: android, string

I am translating my app. Therefore I need to put all texts to strings. The translation worked fine, except two strings. They showed as just numbers. I tried change the string that didn't work to a string that worked in other textviews, but that didn't work. Why is my string showing as numbers.

Here is my java code:

```
TextView repetitionsRemaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.repetitionsRemaining);
repetitionsRemaining.setText(R.string.repetitions_remaining + ":" + " " 
        + currentRepititions + "/" + repetitionsTotal);
```

Here is my string.xml code:

```
<string name="repetitions_remaining">Repetitions remaining</string>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzEz0.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are printing resource ids instead of strings. Use this:

```
TextView repetitionsRemaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.repetitionsRemaining);
repetitionsRemaining.setText(getString(R.string.repetitions_remaining) + ":" + " " + currentRepititions + "/" + repetitionsTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android stores strings in strings.xml as resources. To convert a resource ID to a string you must first call `String repsRemainingStr = getString(R.string.repetitions_remaining)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

> TextView repetitionsRemaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.repetitionsRemaining);
>   repetitionsRemaining.setText(   getresources().getString(R.string.repetitions_remaining) + ":" + " " + currentRepititions + "/" + repetitionsTotal);